# PHP IP address truncated in loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a MySQL table that contains IP addresses:
[Table IP addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN6RJ.png)

[image: (IP, Bloccato, DataCreazione, IDOperatoreCreazione, DataModifica, IDOperatoreModifica)]
When I loop the addresses in PHP, they'll be truncate:

```
string(3) "192"

string(3) "192"

string(3) "192"

string(2) "80"
```

My code:

```
public function getListaIndirizzi(Request $request) {

    // Paginazione
    if (!$request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    "indirizzo1" => "ip",
                    "indirizzo2" => "ip"
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        $indirizzi = IP::whereBetween("IP", [$request->get("indirizzo1"), $request->get("indirizzo2")])->paginate(10);
    } else {
        $indirizzi = IP::paginate(10);
    }

    for($i =0; $i < count($indirizzi); $i++) {
        LogController::debug((string)($indirizzi[$i]["IP"]));
    }
    die;

    return view("lista_indirizzi", ["indirizzi" => $indirizzi]);
}
```

I use Laravel framework

That's my Model, how can I specify that IP field is string not integer?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ip extends Model {

    //
    protected $table = "ip";

    protected $primaryKey = "IP";
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        "IP", "Bloccato"
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'DataCreazione', 'IDOperatoreCreazione', 'DataModifica', 'IDOperatoreModifica'
    ];

}
```

I resolve my problem with this code on my Model:

```
public function getIPAttribute($value) {
        return (string) $value;
}
```

Comment: LogController::debug(($indirizzi[$i]["IP"])) is a function that print a var_dump of parameters

Comment: I wonder how Laravel thought that the field was integer? Was there an `(int)` in the `getIPAttribute()` function before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of your issue is somewhere in the model.

It looks quite like the type of the field in the model is integer, not string. So Laravel (or its ORM) will convert the string to an integer right after fetching from the database and before you work with it.

PoC:

```
<?php
$ip = "192.168.1.1";
echo (int)$ip; // prints "192"
```

Even when you do debug:

```
LogController::debug((string)($indirizzi[$i]["IP"]));
```

Evaluates to `(string)(192)` because `$indirizzi[$i]["IP"]` already is integer "192".